# set submitValue:false for extjs component

Tags: extjs, submit

I have component filled in runtime as part of my form:

```
initComponent() {
    const me = this;
    Ext.apply(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                name: 'BasicIndicatorsContainer',
                // need for recursive submitValue: false
                items: [
                    // controller forms some 32 grids here
                ]
            },
```

When I submit form it generates millions of fields in form data.

How do I made `form.getValues ()` ignore my subcomponents during `form.getValues ()` ?

Comment: So do you have an `Ext.form.Panel` and you want all items have `submitValue: false`?

Comment: Yes, yes, only generated ones, inside concrete subcontainer, rest of the form should submit as normal

Comment: Generation is somewhat complex and uncontrollable, total rewrite is somewhat unacceptable … need to mark result as not submittable

Comment: Is there way to implement on before submit filter handler, to exclude certain excessive  fields by name maybe?

Comment: can you add `submitValue: false` after `name` and before `items` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [defaults](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-defaults) configuration of `Ext.container.Container`. The configs you set here will be applied to every item in the container.

So if the items are form fields, you can set all of their `submitValue` once by applying this on the container:

```
xtype: 'container',
name: 'BasicIndicatorsContainer',
defaults: {
  submitValue: false,
}
```

Actually you can also specify a function here to implement more complex behaviour.

Comment: @jonny Does this solution work for you?